# How to compare goodness of fit between different distributions in R?

Tags: r, distributions, goodness-of-fit

I have some annual maximum data and I want to fit them with some statistical distributions. Theoretically, annual maximum data can be modeled by a Generalized extreme value distribution (GEV), however, this is not always the case. So I want to test which distribution can better describe my data.

As an example, I have tested GEV and Weibull distributions.

```
library(extRemes)
library(eva)
library(fitdistrplus)

Mydata <- c(3,3,2,3,4,3,4,3,2,2,4,3,5,3,3,3,2,5,4,2,2,5,4,5,2,4,3,4,5,4,3,6,4,15,5,2,4,5,3)
fit_mle <- fevd(x=Mydata, method = "MLE", type="GEV",period.basis = "year")
ks.test(x=Mydata, y="pgev",loc=fit_mle$results$par[[1]],
    scale=fit_mle$results$par[[2]],shape=fit_mle$results$par[[3]])
summary(fit_mle)
```

[image]

```
fw <- fitdist(data=Mydata, distr="weibull")
ks.test(x=Mydata, y="pweibull",
    scale=fw$estimate[["scale"]],shape=fw$estimate[["shape"]])
summary(fw)
```

[image]

According to the KS test, both GEV and Weibull are acceptable. However, according to AIC, GEV is better.

My questions are: First, am I correct that GEV is better in this case? Second, is there any goodness of fit test that can be used to compare the goodness of fit between different distributions? Thanks for any help.

Comment: @r2evans Hi, thank you for your reply. But how can we compare the results from two KS test? Is a larger p-value from the KS test better?

Comment: Statistical tests of difference in p-values are extremely dicey (defining the null distribution of p-value differences in a given scenario is difficult); similar issues apply to GOF. I would agree with @user31264 that AIC/BIC are the best way to do this.

Comment: @BenBolker Thanks. Except for AIC and BIC, is there any other goodness of fit test which can compare the results from Weibull and GEV distribution?

Answer (score 1):

Since GEV has better AIC and BIC, it seems better.

You may also try cross-validation.

(To do cross-validation, you should randomlt divide the data by several (maybe 5) pieces, for each piece fit it on other pieces, and test it on this piece, looking at the log-likelihood. The sum of log-likelihoods is what you need.)

Comment: This is so brief it seems more like a comment. Can you provide more information? In particular consider that - even if the OP were to follow your answer - that a later reader may not. Can you provide a little more depth please?

Comment: @Glen_b expanded it a bit

Comment: I think the first line could easily be expanded. Imagine your reader doesn't know much about what AIC and BIC are or they may have heard of them but perhaps are not sure why they might be a good way to choose between distributions.

Comment: He can easily find the info.  "What is AIC and BIC" is not a good question here, anyways, I am not going to do it.

Comment: @user31264 Thank you for your help. Except for AIC and BIC, is there any other goodness of fit test that can be used?

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the Weibull distribution is a special case of the three parameter GEV (at least,from Wikipedia article on GEV - "The shape parameter ξ governs the tail behavior of the distribution. The sub-families defined by ξ = 0, ξ > 0 and ξ < 0  correspond, respectively, to the Gumbel, Fréchet and Weibull families"*, with a true shape parameter < 0 implying a "reverse" Weibull - I suspect this means a shape parameter > 0 is related to a Weibull, but not an expert, so not sure) I don't think it's clear from your results that the shape parameter is significantly > 0.

(* URL = https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_extreme_value_distribution#Link_to_Fr%C3%A9chet,_Weibull_and_Gumbel_families)

Comment: Thanks, but it seems that your answer does not answer my question: is there any goodness of fit test that can be used to compare the goodness of fit between different distributions?